# Are LTS codenames specifically intended to imply reliability?

Tags: release-management

Looking at the [list of codenames](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DevelopmentCodeNames), it seems that the LTS codenames imply or suggest reliability, polish or ease-of-use, while the non-LTS codenames suggest traits other than reliability, such as experimentation or instability.

For example, **hardy**, **precise**, **trusty** and **xenial**, versus **edgy**, **intrepid**, **maverick** and **oneiric**.

Is this deliberate, I wonder?

Comment: Quite possibly. LTSs are also base on Dbian Testing, while regular releases are on Unstable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is deliberate. All codenames are a hint to the features that are to be addressed in that release.

[Reasoning on Oneiric](http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/646):

> What we want is something imaginative, something dreamy. Something sleek and neat, too. Something that has all the precision of T S Eliot’s poetry, matched with the “effable ineffability” of our shared values, friendship and expertise. Something that captures both the competence of ubuntu-devel with the imagination of ayatana.
>
> Which leads us neatly to the Oneiric Ocelot.

And for [Saucy Salamander](http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/1252):

> Which is why, upon not very deep reflection, I would like to introduce you to our mascot for the next six months, the saucy salamander.
>
> The salamander is one of nature’s most magical creatures; they are a strong indicator of a pristine environment, which is a fitting way to describe the new world emerging around Ubuntu Touch – new applications, a new SDK, a gorgeous clean interface. You’ll find salamanders swimming in clear, clean upstreams – which is exactly what’s forming around Ubuntu’s mobile ecosystem. It’s a way of saying ‘thank you’ to the tremendous community that has joined the effort to create a single unified experience from phone to PC, with tons of crisp and stylish core apps made by people from all over the world who want to build something fast, fresh and free. And we’re saucy too – life’s too short to be stodgy or stilted. Our work is our play – we make amazing things for a huge audience, we find space for pretty much every flavour of interface and do it with style.

Not all of the names got an elaborate introduction though.

Mark Shuttleworth's [blog](http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/tag/codename) has a lot more on the codenames and reasoning.